# Play WAV-File in Daemon-Thread

Tags: java, multithreading, audio

How can I play a WAV-File in an infinite loop in a Daemon-Thread? Nothing that I have tested worked. The program always exits after starting without doing anything.

```
public class BackgroundSoundThread extends Thread {
    private final URL url;
    private final AudioInputStream audioStream;
    private final AudioFormat audioFormat;
    private final  SourceDataLine sourceLine;

    public BackgroundSoundThread(URL url) throws IOException, LineUnavailableException, UnsupportedAudioFileException {
        this.setDaemon(true);    
        this.url = url;

        audioStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(getClass().getResource("resources/launcher.wav"));
        audioFormat = audioStream.getFormat();
        DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(SourceDataLine.class, audioFormat);
        sourceLine = (SourceDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
    }

    @Override public void run() {
        try {
            sourceLine.open(audioFormat);
            sourceLine.start();

            int size = (int)(audioFormat.getFrameSize() * audioStream.getFrameLength());
            byte[] data = new byte[size];
            audioStream.read(data, 0, size);
            sourceLine.write(data, 0, size);

            sourceLine.drain();
            sourceLine.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // here is exception handling
        }
    }

    public void pause(boolean b) {
        // what here??
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you starting this thread?

Comment: `this.setDaemon(true)` => did you by any chance mean `this.setDaemon(false)`

Comment: Thread is started in main method.

Comment: If the thread is non daemon it works but the program doesn't close if I call System.exit(0)